# After applied SUPEE 8788 on CE 1.9.2.2, no catalog images in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload, supee-8788

My issue seems kind of unique as I was unable to find any answers yet.

I have a Magento CE 1.9.2.2 running. After applying SUPEE 8788, initially image uploader did not work. Thanks to advice on here got upload running.

But if I use the patched `image.php` file in `app/code/Mage/Catalog/Helper` or in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper` (if it's placed there), all frontend catalog images are not shown, no error message. And if I use the unpatched `image.php` file, uploader in backend does not work, but images show in frontend.

What I already did: 
- Flushed all caches
- flushed browser cache
- re-indexed catalog 
- flushed catalog images
- media folder writable 
- allowed blocks are whitelisted in system > permissions > blocks

I am using Ultimo Theme version 1.14.0. Since images are shown with the 'old' image.php file I do not think it has something to do with Ultimo 1.14.0, although only version 1.15.4 is fully SUPEE 8788 compatible, i.e adding allowed blocks automatically.

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that's the patch that affects symlinks? Do you use any symlinks in your Magento?

Comment: symlinks are set to not allowed in system  > config >  advanced > developer. Checked the source code of the page and discovered a fatal error, probably due to a customisation made in the ultimo theme. Will check this..and post if solved

Comment: I found the code that produces the error: I modified an ultimo theme file to make images to resize in frontend using this modification: https://2ammedia.co.uk/magento-adaptive-resize-resize-to-best-fit/
However, it seems this is in conflict with the new uploader that has been introduced. Will need to dig depper!

Comment: Now solved it. I merged magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php with the image.php file created as shown in guide from https://2ammedia.co.uk/magento-adaptive-resize-resize-to-best-fit/

Comment: glad you figured it out. If you think the answer might help others in the future, feel free to post an answer to your own question!

Comment: After 2 years, have you solve the issue ? Because i am patching my old magento, and i have the same issue as you. Hope you will remerber the solution,
Axel

Answer (score 0):

I had compare the unpatch image.php file and the new image.php file, and there are not much change.

The only change is the two const (XML_NODE_PRODUCT_BASE_IMAGE_WIDTH and XML_NODE_PRODUCT_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH) at the beginging of the Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image class, replace by a new one (XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION)

And the last function validateUploadFile().

I seem to find the solution by only add the two old const, with the new one.

Comment: Please explain in more